# Sending text message SMS without user intervention

Tags: ios, sms, sensors

Is it possible to send sms via iphone without user intervention? I already know about MessageUI framework and MFMessageComposeViewController class, but this option requires user to click Send button when MGMessageComposeViewController is presented. I would like the device to automatically, without my help send a text message when certain conditions are met. (I have some sensors connected to the device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to send sms without user's interaction, consider using some third party gateway. TextMagic provides nice api to send sms, but it is not free. At some point it charges you money. But, they have nice and simple api to use.

Look at this,

http://api.textmagic.com/https-api/textmagic-api-commands#send

Comment: Those SMSes would come from your TextMagic number, not the user's number, though. Twilio is another popular option.

Comment: I'm a little confused about third party support(TextMagic,Twilio). Can I sell an app that uses such APIs in App Store? Do I need to jail brake my iphone?

Comment: You can sell the app. There is nothing wrong with that. It does not violate anything. You just need to pay more to those clients and that's it.

Comment: ok, thats great. If so, I'm very surprised Apple does not provide APIs to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only open a message ready to send but you cannot send it automatically.